# Program with Protocol Buffer can't get linked

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, activemq-classic, protocol-buffers

I have a cpp file in which I am trying to use the message that I created with protocol buffer. However I keep getting that famous "undefined reference" error as follows:

`undefined reference to PointMsg::PointMsg()`

`undefined reference to PointMsg::~PointMsg()`

`undefined reference to PointMsg::~PointMsg()`

Here is the proto file that I have, **Point.proto** :

```
message PointMsg {
   required float x = 1;
   required float y = 2;
   optional float z = 3;
   optional string name = 4 [default=""];

   required string sender = 5;
}
```

After executing proto command generating additional files which contain the necessary functions, I try to use them in my component, which is another file. I give the include as `#include "proto/Point.pb.h"` and I use it as follows:

```
PointMsg pointmsg;
detectObstacle(&pointmsg);
```

In the function what happens is:

```
void detectObstacle(PointMsg* pointmsg)
{   
    // initialize random seed
    srand (time(NULL));

    // generate two numbers
    int x = rand() % 800 + 1;
    int y = rand() % 800 + 1;

    // assign the values to fields
    pointmsg->set_x(x);
    pointmsg->set_y(y);

    cout<<pointmsg->x()<<endl;
    cout<<pointmsg->y()<<endl;

    string sender = "obstacle_detection";
    cout<<sender<<endl;

    pointmsg->set_sender(sender);
    cout<<pointmsg->sender()<<endl;

    return;
}
```

And here are the commands that use to build and link:

```
g++ -I $APR_INCLUDE -I $CMS_HOME/src/main -g -o obstacle_detection.o -c obstacle_detection.cpp

g++ -L $CMS_HOME/src/main/.libs/ -g -o obstacle_detection obstacle_detection.o -lactivemq-cpp -lssl -lprotobuf -pthread
```

And I get that error of undefined reference. I already spent a lot of time on this, couldn't find any solution. People keep saying that I have to add the library at the end, well that's not the solution for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the proto compiler to generate C++ code specific to your protobuf schema (which you seem to have done), and then compile and link *that* code, too! There should be something like a `Point.pb.o` file somewhere.

There isn't a single, fixed library that provides code for all future message types. The public library only contains the common code for the type-agnostic core operations (e.g. field descriptors, serialization, repeated fields). But the leaf code that provides the actual C++ interface to your message type becomes part of *your* code that you must link in yourself.

Comment: I ran the proto compiler to generate .pb files already, I have pb.cc and pb.h files in my folder. So what you are saying is, I should link these two files within my command of g++ as well, or?